# How to fix reading/writing value from .dat file

Tags: java

Please find attached Java code. I am unable to fix and execute the code. If I execute Locations.java, no error message is coming,
at main(MainAdventure.java:30)
at Locations.getLocation(Locations.java:96)

If I execute the MainAdventure.java, getting null pointer exception. 
I tried to debug but no help.Can some one please guide me?

**`MainAdventure.java`**

```
public class MainAdventure {

    private static Locations locations = new Locations();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        /*
         * Change the program to allow players to type full words, or phrases, then move
         * to the correct location based upon their input. The player should be able to
         * type commands such as "Go West", "run South", or just "East" and the program
         * will move to the appropriate location if there is one. As at present, an
         * attempt to move in an invalid direction should print a message and remain in
         * the same place.
         *
         * Single letter commands (N, W, S, E, Q) should still be available.
         */

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        Map<String, String> vocabulary = new HashMap<String, String>();
        vocabulary.put("QUIT", "Q");
        vocabulary.put("NORTH", "N");
        vocabulary.put("SOUTH", "S");
        vocabulary.put("WEST", "W");
        vocabulary.put("EAST", "E");

        Location currentLocation = locations.getLocation(1);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(currentLocation.getDescription());

            if (currentLocation.getLocationID() == 0) {
                break;
            }

            Map<String, Integer> exits = currentLocation.getExits();
            System.out.print("Available exits are ");
            for (String exit : exits.keySet()) {
                System.out.print(exit + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            String direction = scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            if (direction.length() > 1) {
                String[] words = direction.split(" ");
                for (String word : words) {
                    if (vocabulary.containsKey(word)) {
                        direction = vocabulary.get(word);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (exits.containsKey(direction)) {
                currentLocation = locations.getLocation(currentLocation.getExits().get(direction));

            } else {
                System.out.println("You cannot go in that direction");
            }
        }

        locations.close();

    }
}
```

**`Locations.java`**

```
public class Locations implements Map<Integer, Location> {

    private static Map<Integer, Location> locations = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Location>();
    private static Map<Integer, IndexRecord> index = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private static RandomAccessFile ra;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (RandomAccessFile rao = new RandomAccessFile("locations_rand.dat", "rwd")) {
            rao.writeInt(locations.size());
            int indexSize = locations.size() * 3 * Integer.BYTES;
            int locationStart = (int) (indexSize + rao.getFilePointer() + Integer.BYTES);
            rao.writeInt(locationStart);

            long indexStart = rao.getFilePointer();

            int startPointer = locationStart;
            rao.seek(startPointer);

            for (Location location : locations.values()) {
                rao.writeInt(location.getLocationID());
                rao.writeUTF(location.getDescription());
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (String direction : location.getExits().keySet()) {
                    if (!direction.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
                        builder.append(direction);
                        builder.append(",");
                        builder.append(location.getExits().get(direction));
                        builder.append(",");
                    }
                }
                rao.writeUTF(builder.toString());

                IndexRecord record = new IndexRecord(startPointer, (int) (rao.getFilePointer() - startPointer));
                index.put(location.getLocationID(), record);

                startPointer = (int) rao.getFilePointer();
            }

            rao.seek(indexStart);
            for (Integer locationID : index.keySet()) {
                rao.writeInt(locationID);
                rao.writeInt(index.get(locationID).getStartByte());
                rao.writeInt(index.get(locationID).getLength());
            }

        }

    }

    // 1. This first four bytes will contain the number of locations (bytes 0-3)
    // 2. The next four bytes will contain the start offset of the locations section
    // (bytes 4-7)
    // 3. The next section of the file will contain the index (the index is 1692
    // bytes long. It will start at byte 8 and end at byte 1699
    // 4. The final section of the file will contain the location records (the
    // data). It will start at byte 1700

    static {
        try {
            ra = new RandomAccessFile("locations_rand.dat", "rwd");
            int numLocations = ra.readInt();
            long locationStartPoint = ra.readInt();

            while (ra.getFilePointer() < locationStartPoint) {
                int locationId = ra.readInt();
                int locationStart = ra.readInt();
                int locationLength = ra.readInt();

                IndexRecord record = new IndexRecord(locationStart, locationLength);
                index.put(locationId, record);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException in static initializer: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Location getLocation(int locationId) throws IOException {

        IndexRecord record = index.get(locationId);
        ra.seek(record.getStartByte());
        int id = ra.readInt();
        String description = ra.readUTF();
        String exits = ra.readUTF();
        String[] exitPart = exits.split(",");

        Location location = new Location(locationId, description, null);

        if (locationId != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < exitPart.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("exitPart = " + exitPart[i]);
                System.out.println("exitPart[+1] = " + exitPart[i + 1]);
                String direction = exitPart[i];
                int destination = Integer.parseInt(exitPart[++i]);
                location.addExit(direction, destination);
            }
        }

        return location;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return locations.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return locations.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return locations.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return locations.containsValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Location get(Object key) {
        return locations.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Location put(Integer key, Location value) {
        return locations.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public Location remove(Object key) {
        return locations.remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends Integer, ? extends Location> m) {

    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        locations.clear();

    }

    @Override
    public Set<Integer> keySet() {
        return locations.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Location> values() {
        return locations.values();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<Integer, Location>> entrySet() {
        return locations.entrySet();
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        ra.close();
    }
}
```

**`Location.java`**

```
public class Location implements Serializable {
    private final int locationID;
    private final String description;
    private final Map<String, Integer> exits;

    private long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Location(int locationID, String description, Map<String, Integer> exits) {
        this.locationID = locationID;
        this.description = description;
        if (exits != null) {
            this.exits = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>(exits);
        } else {
            this.exits = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        }
        this.exits.put("Q", 0);
    }

    public int getLocationID() {
        return locationID;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getExits() {
        return new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>(exits);
    }

    protected void addExit(String direction, int location) {
        exits.put(direction, location);
    }
}
```

It looks like that the error I get, is caused by `ra.seek(record.getStartByte());` inside `Locations` class, at the method `getLocation(int locationId)`;.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-yN5dr40uN9Fh4kr7ka_oe4OlF1cZCuY/view) is the **.dat** file.

Comment: This is a lot of code and you are not likely to get help with such a question. The point is not to paste all your code and ask for someone to debug it. You should instead spend 2-3 minutes to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then reformat your question. If you do that, I guarantee, there will be plenty of volunteers to help you. Enjoy SO!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-yN5dr40uN9Fh4kr7ka_oe4OlF1cZCuY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you..I tried a lot and debugged that the problem is coming from ra.seek(record.getStartByte());  and Location currentLocation = locations.getLocation(1); But i am unable to fix it

Comment: Well, you should add that to your question! That the problem is coming from **that** line of code! Also, post the exact error message that you get from your compiler. What is going wrong?

Comment: One more update: I shared same code to my friend, who is able to run without any issues. I did not modify any code changes.